# How to import wx on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, python, python-2.7, pip, wxpython

I have tried installing it using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk3.0
```

But still when I run a py script with import wx it throws an error 'no module named wx' on Python 2.x and Python 3.x

I also tried installing it using pip:

```
pip install wxpython
```

which gives me an error saying failed building wheel for wxpython.

I also tried building wxpython from
[source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wxPython/4.0.0b2).

but it shows a network error whenever I try to download the tar.gz file. I have unsuccesfully tried downloading it from multiple networks.

Please help.

Comment: Probably you're using a virtual environment.

Comment: If that's the case, use this command: `pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 wxPython    `

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-wxgtk3.0 python-wxgtk3.0-dev
```

Then check if wx works in Python 2.x as follows:

```
$ python
>>> import wx
```

**Example code**

1. Save the following code as `wxPython-window.py`
2. Make it executable.
3. Change directories using `cd` to the parent directory of wxPython-window.py
4. Run the code with `./wxPython-window.py`

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python

   import wx      
   app = wx.App()
   frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'win.py')
   frame.Show()
   app.MainLoop()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxtools
```

Comment: Same issue, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

please check if you have all necessary libraries installed
(here is a link for different OS like Ubuntu 16 [Libs needed for wx](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/vagrant/ubuntu-16.04/bootstrap.sh))

```
# Install necessary development tools, libs, etc.
apt-get install -y build-essential dpkg-dev

apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev
apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev libtiff-dev \
    libsdl1.2-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
    libnotify-dev freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libsm-dev \
    libwebkitgtk-dev libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev \
    libxtst-dev
```